# OSx php7.1 problems

Tags: php, macos, symfony, macos-sierra, spl

I am new on OSx and have problem with my php installation and SPL functions. Sometimes when I'm trying to access symfony project through apache I'v got an errors showed below.

When spl_autoloader tries to load ParameterBag class:

> Warning: class_implements(): Class /.[^.]+.twig$/ does not exist and could not be loaded

Stack trace:

```
1 in DebugClassLoader.php line 243
2 at ErrorHandler->handleError('2', 'class_implements(): Class /\.[^.]+\.twig$/ does not exist and could not be loaded', '/Users/mtertishniy/sites/dvsota/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Debug/DebugClassLoader.php', '243', array('class' => 'Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag', 'file' => '/Users/mtertishniy/sites/dvsota/vendor/composer/../symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/ParameterBag.php', 'exists' => true, 'refl' => object(ReflectionClass), 'name' => 'Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag', 'notice' => array(), 'len' => '8', 'ns' => 'Symfony\', 'parent' => false, 'parentInterfaces' => array('/\.[^.]+\.twig$/' => '1'), 'deprecatedInterfaces' => array(), 'interface' => '/\.[^.]+\.twig$/'))
3 at class_implements('/\.[^.]+\.twig$/') in DebugClassLoader.php line 243
4 at DebugClassLoader->loadClass('Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag')
5 at spl_autoload_call('Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag') in Request.php line 247
```

Other strange error:

> OutOfMemoryException in DebugClassLoader.php line 243:
>
> Error: Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 140495632205216 bytes)

I've debugged this error and found that in this case autoloader trying to load malformed interface:
[image]

I've been installed httpd and PHP 7.1 from brew.

My php modules:

```
$ php -m
[PHP Modules]
bcmath
bz2
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dba
dom
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gd
gettext
hash
iconv
imagick
intl
json
ldap
libxml
mbstring
mcrypt
mysqli
mysqlnd
odbc
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
PDO_ODBC
pdo_sqlite
Phar
posix
readline
Reflection
session
shmop
SimpleXML
soap
sockets
SPL
sqlite3
standard
sysvmsg
sysvsem
sysvshm
tokenizer
wddx
xdebug
xml
xmldiff
xmlreader
xmlrpc
xmlwriter
xsl
yaml
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]
Xdebug
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally figured out! This is bug in core php < 7.2.
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=74015

The issue is closed.

Answer (score 0):

Because you limit is very big.

You're trying to allocate 140495GB of data.

You either need to :

- Reconsider how much ram your application need (recommended)
- Increase the memory limit to 140495GB (not recommended).

Try to allocate 128MB ro 256MB ... of data.

Comment: @KorozCo I use the same limit as on my Linux server and everything works fine.


140495632205216 bytes = 140495,63220521601 GB. It's not the main problem.


The problem is that the script stops working at random time (problems about names described above).

For example, for a request 1, everything works fine, but request 2 and 3, there are problems, and then it's good again. And this happens by accident when the DebugClassLoader tries to load SPL interfaces (which names seems to be wrong parsed)!

Comment: @koninka, Did you try limit 128MB or 256MB or 512MB?

Comment: of course, my memory limit is 1GB. And it's not the main point!

**I've debugged this error and found that in this case autoloader trying to load malformed interface**

Comment: @koninka Ты решил свою ошибку?

Comment: try `composer install`

Comment: @imanali-mamadiev нет, не решил. composer install и остальное в том же духе не работает. Может у меня инсталляция кривая в совокупности c httpd, не знаю

Comment: @koninka, ты пробовал установить новый проект через composer?